# How can I compare 2 lists with regex in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 lists to compare. `list1` has expected values and `list2` has actual values. How can I compare both lists with regex?

```
list1 = ["name", "id", "module name", "start date", "end date"]
list2 = ["s.no", "report parameters", "name", "id", "initiator id", "module name", "test name", "start date", "end date"....]
for i in range(len(list1 )):
    match = re.match(list1[i], list2)
    assert match, ("Lists are not matching")
```

`Error: re.match expects string or buffer (not list)`

Comment: Regex is for matching a string against a pattern. You have two lists. Why would you want to use regex? What is your desired output? What does it mean to you for lists to match? Do you mean each element in `list1` is found in `list2`? If so, `set(list1) <= set(list2)` should be all you need.

Comment: I have 2 lists which contains some strings. So I want to use regex for exact text comparison.

Comment: Using regex for exact string comparison between lists is using the wrong tool. For that matter, it is a wrong tool even for exact comparison between two strings. It's like "I have soup. So I want to use chainsaw to eat it. How do I do that?" If you really need that, I guess we can talk about chainsaws, but spoons work much better for soup. Have you tried the `set` solution I posted (assuming I guessed correctly what you are trying to do)?

Comment: Does `print([k in list2 for k in list1])` doing a check per item of list1 to see if it is in list2 work for you?

Comment: @Amadan, set(list1) <= set(list2) does worked.. Thanks !!!